# How to add search on mat-options and not on mat-optgroup

Tags: angular

I can't find a way to add search option because my mat-option is in mat-optgroup, any suggestions?

```html
<mat-optgroup *ngIf="company.groups?.length" [label]="company.name" multiple>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let group of company.groups; trackBy: trackById" [value]="group.id">
      {{ group.name }}
    </mat-option>
</mat-optgroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested to use search textbox inside the mat-select dropdown panel control then please go through the demo "mat-select-with-grouping-and-search" https://stackblitz.com/edit/select-group-search